# Create Code 128 Barcode with Zend Barcode Component that contains an FNC3 function character

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, barcode, code128

I'm trying to work out how to inlclude an FNC3 control character in my Zend Barcode.

For example this barcode contains the FNC3 character and then 0B

[image: barcode]

Compare that to a barcode that doesn't contain this character.

[image]

I am unable to work out how to (1) change the charset of a type 128 barcode. (2) Include a control character (FNC1-4) in a type128 barcode.

I've tried passing though all kinds of combinations like the following into the 'text' param of the options array.
http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.barcode.objects.html

Is this possible? How does one pass an FNC3 Character. Is this the literal string 'FNC3' or am I missing something.

Edit:

I have tried using ü / Ç characters in my text string but PHP trips up every time.

Answer (score 2):

Seems there is no way to include FNC3 character in current version of \Zend\Barcode\Object\Code128. I would made a copy of Code128.php, replaced 'FNC3' to a character with a charcode greater 128, e.g. `chr(228)` (it's ASCII code of the character in Barcode Font according to http://www.barcoderesource.com/code128_barcode_map.html):

```
protected $charSets = array(
    'A' => array(
    /*...*/
        chr(228), 'FNC2', 'SHIFT', 'Code C', 'Code B', 'FNC4', 'FNC1',
    /*...*/
    'B' => array(
    /*...*/
        chr(228), 'FNC2', 'SHIFT', 'Code C', 'FNC4', 'Code A', 'FNC1',
```

and then use chr(228) in your strings (e.g. `chr(228).'0B'`). And finally you can override original class using composer's loader or creating a module to do it in standard way.

Comment: Thanks. I've solved it a different way now, but I appreciate. I got frustrated having to manually fork and maintain my own repositories every time I need to workaround a bad decision or difference in opinion made in ZF2 so I try to avoid it.

Comment: How did you end up solving this? Rather interested in this as we need to generate some FNC3 codes.

Comment: The Zend Barcode plugin does exactly what it says it will do. It generates a Code128 barcode. It doesn't make the logical decisions (code set shifting etc, such as in the GS1-128 standards) on when and where to shift because that's the responsibility of the client.